# How to get CheckBoxPreference value within the Receiver/Service in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, receiver, checkboxpreference

I use `CheckBoxPreference` in my `PreferenceActivity` to set a value. Later on, I want to check that value from Receiver and/or Service. `findPreference()` method is not available from that context. I know, that this preference value is stored in `SharedPreferences` anyway, but what is the key? How could I get the value of the checkbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know, that this preference value is stored in SharedPreferences anyway, but what is the key?

Whatever value you have for `android:key` in your preference XML.

> How could I get the value of the checkbox?

Call `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` to get the `SharedPreferences`, then call `getBoolean()` with the key you used in `android:key`.

Comment: @jacek: You could always buy a book or three... :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your preferences XML you'll have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference android:enabled="true"
    android:title="@string/s_pref" android:key="@string/pref"
    android:defaultValue="@string/d_pref"></CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Your strings.xml would have something like this:

```
<string name="pref">my.package.PREF</string>
<string name="s_pref">Prompt</string>
<string name="d_pref">true</string>
```

Your Activity's onCreate() would have something like this:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
pref = prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref), true));
```

If you want to do something when someone changes the preferences, add an onActivityResult() to your activity and start the preferences activity with startActivityForResult().  When onActivityResult() is invoked with whatever result code you want to indicate a change in preferences, you can do another getDefaultSharedPreferences().

The shared preferences framework automatically persists the data... you don't have to actively deal with it yourself, though you can if you wish with an OnPreferenceChangeListener in the preferences activity

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would add to CommonsWare's answer is, since you mentioned a service, you can put whatever preferences the service needs to know about in its Intent extras.  For example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("mypref", prefs.getString("mypref", ""));
startService(intent);
```

Comment: In response to your comment the documentation, there is actually a pretty good discussion, with example code, here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I haven't found anything about retrieving data from built-in `CheckBoxPreference` (other than getting the `CheckBoxPreference` itself).

Answer (score 0):

try to write this in your service

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
```

and here specify the key that you have used in xml

```
 if(preferences.getBoolean(your key ,true))
            {
```

hope this help .